# ReactJS integration with libraries using getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the best approach for rendering components using libraries for which direct access to the DOM is required (e.g. `document.getElementById()`) ? Currently I got things working thanks to `setTimeout` :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            myCoolGraphLibrary.createChart({
                container : "myChartContainer",
                series : [...],
                ...
            });    
        },1000);
        return (<div id="myChartContainer"></div>);
    }
}
```

Without setTimeout, the container is not yet available in the DOM so the call to createChart fails.

Is there a better design pattern for achieving this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the lifecycle methods.  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html

In particular, you'll want to use `componentDidMount` to run any code that depends on the DOM elements existing.  If you're adding event listeners, be sure to remove them in `componentWillUnmount`

EDIT:  In response to your comment, your code would look like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        myCoolGraphLibrary.createChart({
            container : "myChartContainer",
            series : [...],
            ...
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (<div id="myChartContainer"></div>);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you'd move the whole `setTimeout` block to componentDidMount ?

Comment: You wouldn't need the `setTimeout` block because you're guaranteed that when `componentDidMount` fires, the DOM elements that your component renders will exist

Comment: @taylorc93: Well, `componentDidMount` is called when the component and all its children are created and mounted, but that doesn't mean that the component's *parent* was already added to the document (and it most likely isn't). Depending on what the third party library does, pushing DOM access to the next tick might still be necessary.

Comment: @taylorc93 Works fine with your solution, thanks, but I also had to refresh the graph in `componentDidUpdate` because of a double rendering of the component : once with the initial state, and once due to some async `state` update. I mark your answer as accepted but it would be nice if you could also consider this in your code sample.

Comment: @FelixKling, you're right, I was just assuming that any DOM elements that were needed were going to be rendered by this component